# What's are the naming conventions on COM libraries? When do I choose .ocx, .oca, .tlb, .olb?

Tags: winapi, com, activex

**EDIT**: Since the original wording of my question caused much frowning I re-phrased it. Sorry about the confusion.

Until now all my COM DLLs had the extension .dll, but I assume there are some rules about that. I know there are .ocx, .oca, .tlb and .olb files. I'm aware that these files all contain "COM stuff" but what exactly?

- What are these files in general: .ocx, .oca, .tlb, .olb?
- What is the difference between an OLB and a TLB?
- What is the difference between TLB and OCX?
- What is the difference between .ocx and .oca?
- When should I name my library .ocx and when .tlb? If they contain a certain kind of feature?
- Which properties do my libraries have to have to use a certain extension?

Comment: Yes and it didn't help much. For example: "difference between olb and tlb" just yielded the full names (Object Library, type library) assumptions of other users, and an Experts Exchange question :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **.ocx**

  - ActiveX Control
- **.oca**

  - Extended type library/custom control cache file that goes along with a .ocx
- **.tlb**

  - Contains the definitions of the COM interfaces and types contained in its associated COM library. It is a cross language "header file".
- **.olb**

  - A Microsoft Object Library file that contains information referenced by Microsoft Office components.

Comment: What do you mean by "user interface data"? What is the difference between "user interface data" and an ActiveX control?

Comment: Type Libraries (tlb) contain the definitions of the COM interfaces and types contained in it's associated COM library. It is a cross language "header file" (if you're familiar with c/c++). I think that's a typo in Mark's answer.